# What is the google play in-app product "description" used for?

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I cannot figure out where the mandatory "description" that you enter for in-app products actually appears, besides as a property of the "Bundle" when you check to see what a user has purchased...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it from [getSkuDetails](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails)().  Given that and that you can add translations I'm guessing it's supposed a way to be able to display a list of products all based on the information that get from the API. In theory your app could display a list of products with all the information the user would want, and you could change them from the play store without updating your app.

As far as I can tell the play store never displays this string.  I'm not sure why it's required.